# Tumblr - Facebook post like status statistics

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, tumblr

I want to implement the following features.

From my server I want to write a script which will authenticate a user's tumblr and facebook account and will extract

> like statistics comparison data

from corresponding posts.

Anyone have any ideas.

I tired to extract the information using the tumblr API but did not get any useful information to fulfill the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr *likes* are classed as **post notes**.

From the [API documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) you can get post note information as follows:

http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/BLOGNAME.tumblr.com/posts?id=XXXX&notes_info=true

Adding the parameter `notes_info=true` will return the note / like count.